# GridView : access item view, knowing item viewmodel on selection

Tags: winrt-xaml

I'm using a GridView in an MVVM context.

In the GridView events as "ItemClick" or "SelectionChanged", I can only get ViewModel objects.
For instance :

```
private void GridView_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // e.AddedItems are xxxViewModel
}
```

Now, I would like to access the **item view corresponding to the item viewmodel** (even if considered as MVVM violation).

Any idea how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The items in e.AddedItems and e.RemovedItems are objects. You will need to cast them, something like this:

```
var added = e.AddedItems.OfType<MyModel>().Cast<MyModel>();
```

Make sense?

Best of luck!